# Android AsyncTask terminated before completion if connection or device is slow

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an `AsyncTask` where I invoke a method that download some data from internet and performs certain operations.

In the emulator this works always despite the connection speed but on real devices if connection or device isn't fast this task is automatically terminated. I don't know why, but probably there is some kind of default timeout in Android default task management.

**How could I fix this problem?**

**How to force the completion of the task always?**

Here my code

```
myTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            ProgressDialog pd;
            boolean correctlyInitialized = true;


            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                pd= new ProgressDialog(CatcherTree.this);


                pd.setCancelable(false);
                try {
                    pd.show();
                } catch (Error e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                long t = System.currentTimeMillis();

               //this method requires time to complete
                updateAllDataSet(CatcherTree.this);

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void rate) {
                pd.dismiss();

            }
        }.execute();
```

Comment: `this task is automatically terminated` - how did you know that?

Comment: If the connection is fast, no problem, if is slower the waiting dialog is dismissed without any crash or error but the operation is suspended. and If I try to invoke the method outside the AsyncTask is completed correctly despite the slowness

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTasks rely on a worker thread to do the background job, and threads do not just *disappear*. So my guess is that the worker thread is throwing an exception and terminating.

Look through your logcat for the exception, or better yet - handle exceptions correctly in `updateAllDataSet()`.

Comment: the procedure doesn't crash itself, but is interrupted due to the hight time to complete if the connection or the device is slow

Comment: How did you reach that conclusion?

Comment: I have debugged the app and no connection interruption or other kind of exception happens. If the connection is fast, no problem, if is slower the waiting dialog is dismissed without any crash or error but the operation is suspended. and If I try to invoke the method outside the AsyncTask is completed correctly despite the slowness

Comment: So is onPostExecute being called? If not - then how is the PD dismnissing? If so - then the task was completed.

Comment: the dialog is dismissed also if the task in doInbackground() is not completed on slowness circumstances... this is my problem

Comment: Put a breakpoint on onPostExecute() and see if it's being called.